# does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Tags: php, magento2

I have exception when I ceate model.Here is that exception:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Training4\Vendor\Model\Training4_Vendor2Product does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Training4\Vendor\Model\Training4_Vendor2Product does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject
```

Magento version is 2.4.4
\Training4\Vendor\Model\Training4_Vendor2Product

```
<?php


namespace Training4\Vendor\Model;


use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Training4_Vendor2Product extends AbstractModel
{
    const vendor_id='id';

    protected $_idFieldName  = self::vendor_id;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Training4_Vendor2Product::class);
    }
}
```

\Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Training4_Vendor2Product

```
<?php


namespace Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Training4_Vendor2Product extends AbstractDb
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('training4_vendor2product','id');
    }
}
```

\Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Training4_Vendor2Product\Collection

```
<?php


namespace Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Training4_Vendor2Product;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Training4\Vendor\Model\Training4_Vendor2Product::class,
            \Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Training4_Vendor2Product::class);
    }
}
```

in \Training4\Vendor\Model\Training4_Vendor2Product,I have already extends Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel,I don't know why that exception occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add dependency in di.xml

```
<virtualType name="HelenOfTroy\Webinar\Model\ResourceModel\SpecificSpeakers\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">training4_vendor2product</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Training4\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Training4_Vendor2Product</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Comment: the name of the class should without underline,maybe it the rule of magento2

Comment: yes you are right, it is class name issue.